# What is the universal property of being the maximal common subobject of two objects in a semisimple category?

Tags: ct.category-theory, abelian-categories, universal-property

Imagine a semisimple abelian category $\mathcal{C}$, for example representations of a finite group.
Take two (nonsimple) objects $X, Y$ that are subobjects of a common object $Z$, and decompose them into simples, say $X \cong X_1 \oplus X_2 \oplus \cdots \oplus X_n$ and $Y \cong Y_1 \oplus Y_2 \oplus \cdots \oplus Y_m$.
If some of the $X_i$ and $Y_j$ are isomorphic and are being mapped onto the same objects in $Z$, say $X_{i_k} \cong Y_{j_k}$ for $k \in \{1, \ldots K\}$, then $X$ and $Y$ have a common subobject $S$, namely $S := X_{i_1} \oplus X_{i_2} \oplus \cdots \oplus X_{i_K}$ such that $S \hookrightarrow X \hookrightarrow Z = S \hookrightarrow Y \hookrightarrow Z$. It is a maximal object with this property, all other common subobjects are subobjects of it.

This looks a lot like a universal property, but I can't figure out which one. What especially intrigues me that I'm looking not for any objects, but for subobjects. How do I encode that into the universal property?

Comment: What you've written doesn't uniquely determine $S$. Think about the case that $C = \text{Vect}$.

Comment: (If this were a universal property, $S$ would be the terminal object in the category of triples $(S, i_X, i_Y)$ where $S$ is an object and $i_X : S \to X, i_Y : S \to Y$ are monomorphisms. You don't often see universal properties with conditions on the morphisms like that, and indeed even for an innocuous category like $\text{Vect}$ I think this category fails to have a terminal object almost all the time.)

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, No, I think you've misunderstood something. For the case of $\mathrm{Vect}$, you have $X = \mathbb{C}^n$ and $Y = \mathbb{C}^m$. Then $S = \mathbb{C}^{\min(n,m)}$.

Comment: If the $X_i$ are all mutually nonisomorphic and the $Y_j$ as well, then it is, I believe, the product in the category of subobjects of the coend $\Omega_{\mathcal{C}}$, which is the direct sum of all simples. But I'm unsure about this, and I don't know how to get rid of the additional assumption.

Comment: I mean you haven't uniquely determined $S$ as a _subobject_. What are the maps $S \to X, S \to Y$ in your example?

Comment: With the additional assumption in my comment above, any two such maps are related by in isomorphism of subobjects. It seems that without it, one can either drop the requirement of defining $S$ with particular monomorphisms and just ask for them to exist, or one can modify the question the way I did now. Although the latter choice makes the question easy (I'm giving an answer below).

Comment: Yes, now the construction has a universal property, but it's not the same construction. E.g. in the case of $\text{Vect}$ you don't get $\mathbb{C}^{\text{min}(n, m)}$ but just the intersection of two subspaces of some ambient vector space.

Comment: I'm still interested whether I can recover my original formulation in a meaningful way. How about this: "Given two objects $X$ and $Y$, what is 'the' minimal object $S$ such that all morphisms from $X$ to $Y$ factor through $S$?" For $\mathrm{Vect}$, that's again $\mathbb{C}^{\min(n,m)}$.

Comment: If this exists in general, it should be like this: Choosing an order of the $N$ simples, every object corresponds to an $N$-tuple of nonnegative integers, counting the multiplicities of the respective simples in it. Then I want the universal property characterising "Take the minimum in each entry".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can define the category of subobjects of $Z$, where the objects are subobjects of $Z$ and the morphisms have to commute with the monomorphisms of the subobjects.
In this category, $S$ is simply the product of $X$ and $Y$.